# CORs inline material for AFrame

Tags: aframe

`<a-sphere material="src:url(...)"></a-sphere>`

I get:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Other resources not inline do work with CORs. Also I have the newest AFrame version working.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the resource to explicitly allow images from other domains.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/asset-management-system.html#cross-origin

Comment: I was hoping for crossorigin for inline urls to be possible

Answer (score 0):

That means the resource is not being served with CORS headers. The server does not allow it.